# What is 6/2(3), 1 or 9? According to PEMDAS M > D so it should be 1!

Tags: arithmetic

Pretty much what question says. `6÷2x3 = 1` or `6÷2x3 = 9`

Given PEMDAS, I'd bet `2x3 = 6, 6÷6 = 1`. otherwise person would have put parenthesis.

But google and wolframalpha say 9

Comment: PEMDAS more often meant as $P>E >(MD)>(AS)$ rather than $P>E>M>D>A>S$. With the interpretation of the title, one would also argue that A>S, but oddly enough no one ever asks whether $9-5+3=1$ or $7$.

Comment: because i see number `5` as `-5` not as `(9) - (5) + (3)` but rather `+9  -5 +3`

Comment: that question just says PEMDAS is not absolute rule and in fact is insufficient at times

Comment: You've more or less answered your own question with your first comment. If you view subtraction the same as addition then you might as well start viewing division as the same thing as multiplication, then it is $6\times \frac{1}{2} \times 3$ which is unambiguously $9$

Comment: lol pretty nice